# Microsoft Excel lookup match without sorting data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2003

Have a value list and need to insert points by looking up the  data table.  Data table has value for points in 1000 increments.  Actual value that I lookup will not be rounded to 1000 so I tried using Index and match, but I need to sort the data for less than criteria or greater than criteria.  I do not want to sort the data ascending or descending.  Is there anyway to achieve this.[image: LOOKUP EXCEL]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the lookup value instead of using greater/less than:

```
=INDEX(E$4:E$12, MATCH(ROUND(G4,-3),D$4:D$12,0))
```

The `ROUND` will convert 16,368 to 16,000 which will be used for the exact match, and in case of 11,549, it will become 12,000 for another exact match.

Comment: This worked like charm Jerry...Great help!! Please help for similar situation with values increment of 5s. 10, 15, 20, 25.  I need to round the value. E.g. up to 12.5 to 10 OR greater 12.5 to 15.

Comment: @roman_bull For increments of 5, you can use `MROUND()`: `=INDEX(E$4:E$12, MATCH(MROUND(G4,5),D$4:D$12,0))`

Comment: You made my day...!!!

Comment: @roman_bull You're welcome :)